# How to display custom image on cart page in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to display custom image of product on cart page in Magento.

**Config.xml** file

```
<checkout>
    <rewrite>
        <cart_item_renderer>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Block_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer</cart_item_renderer>
    </rewrite>
</checkout>
```

I have added below code in **Block/Checkout/Cart/Item/Renderer.php** file

```
<?php
class ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Block_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer{

    public function getProductThumbnail()
    {
        $item = $this->_item;
        $customize_data = $item->getData('customize_data');
        $customize_image = $item->getData('customize_image');

        $results_data = $item->getOptionByCode("customizer_data")->getValue();
        if(!is_null($results_data)){
            $results = unserialize($results_data); 
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir()."/skin/";
            $_product = $item->getProduct()->load();
            $customize_image = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail',$path.'adminhtml/default/default/images/logo.gif');

            //$customize_image = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail',$results['image']);
        }

        if (!empty($customize_image)) {
            return $customize_image;
        } else {
            return parent::getProductThumbnail();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried ***$customize_image*** with image **"URL", "Path" and "Data (`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG....`)"** but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution. You have override Core class, I have added below class.

Create helper "**Customezerimage.php**" in **Helper** in custom module

```
<?php
class ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Helper_Customezerimage extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image {
    public function setCustomeImage($path){
        $this->_imageFile = $path;
        $this->_setModel(Mage::getModel('productcustomizer/product_image'));
        $this->_getModel()->setCustomeBaseFile($this->_imageFile);
        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        try {
            $model = $this->_getModel();
            $url = $model->getUrl();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $url = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($this->getPlaceholder());
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Create Model "**Image.php**" in **Model/Product** directory in custom module.

```
    <?php 
class ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Model_Product_Image extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image{

    public function setCustomeBaseFile($baseFile){
        if (!file_exists($baseFile)) {
            throw new Exception(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image file was not found.'));
        }
        $this->_newFile = $this->_baseFile = $baseFile;
        return $this;
    }

    public function saveCustomeImage($file = ""){
        if(empty($file)){
            $file = $this->_newFile;
        }
        Mage::log($file);
        $this->getImageProcessor()->save($file);
        return ;
    }

    public function getUrl(){

        $baseDir = Mage::getBaseDir();
        $path = str_replace($baseDir . DS, "", $this->_newFile);
        return Mage::getBaseUrl() . str_replace(DS, '/', $path);
    }
}
```

Now you can set custom image path that you want to display in cart like below

```
<?php
class ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Block_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer{
    public function getProductThumbnail()
    {
        $item = $this->_item;
        $customize_data = $item->getData('customize_data');
        $customize_image = $item->getData('customize_image');

        $results_data = $item->getOptionByCode("customizer_data")->getValue();
        if(!is_null($results_data)){
            $results = unserialize($results_data); 
            $imagePathFull = $customize_image;

            $_product = $item->getProduct();
            $image = $imagePathFull;
            return $this
                ->helper('productcustomizer/customezerimage')
                ->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->setCustomeImage($image);
        }else{
            return parent::getProductThumbnail();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is the idea. The init function you are calling is creating the issue for you. Do something like this as you have already done the override of that class.

```
public function getProductThumbnail1()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->_productThumbnail)) {
            return $this->_productThumbnail;
        }
        return $this->getSkinUrl('images/jhonson.jpg');
        //return $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail');
    }
```

Add this function in that class you have already overridden which is `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer`. Now in your `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` file or whatever your file is call this function like this `echo $this->getProductThumbnail1()` rather than this `echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(180)`.

Comment: I am developing extension so I can't make changes in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`. If you have any other way then Please let me know.